# Spring Boot shuts down after running for few hours

Tags: spring-boot

I did see quite a few posts related to this and tried the solutions suggested (one I was already following). 
I am running a spring boot app which has spring batch and camel routes reading from AMQ. The app does not terminate ever on our standalone linux box unless we specifically shut it down. But on one of the other environment which has multi-node setup on 2 different linux boxes (not clustered) but are connected via spring cloud's eureka goes down abruptly after running for few hours. Additionally, I tried seeing the logs and I do not see any errors whatsoever.
I have not been able to figure out what could be the root cause. Does anyone have any idea around why such a thing would happen?

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.my.org</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-proj</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <name>my-proj</name>
    <description>My Project</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <ml.jersey.version>1.17</ml.jersey.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>Camden.SR5</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
                <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>2.19.2</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-feign</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-eureka</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- MarkLogic -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.marklogic</groupId>
            <artifactId>marklogic-client-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <version>${ml.jersey.version}</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ -->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-apache-client4</artifactId>
            <version>${ml.jersey.version}</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ -->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
            <version>${ml.jersey.version}</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ -->
        </dependency>

        <!-- Camel -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- ActiveMQ -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-activemq</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
            <artifactId>activemq-camel</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
            <artifactId>activemq-pool</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Application class

```
package com.my.org;

import javax.jms.ConnectionFactory;

import org.apache.activemq.camel.component.ActiveMQComponent;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EnableEurekaClient;
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.feign.EnableFeignClients;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaClient
@EnableFeignClients
public class MyBatchApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyBatchApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean(name = "activemq")
    public ActiveMQComponent createComponent(ConnectionFactory factory) {
        ActiveMQComponent activeMQComponent = new ActiveMQComponent();
        activeMQComponent.setConnectionFactory(factory);
        return activeMQComponent;
    }

    @Bean
    public MarkLogicClient markLogicClient() {
        return new MarkLogicJavaClientImpl();
    }

}
```

Start script

```
nohup $JAVA_HOME/bin/java -Xmx1024m -Xms1024m -Dspring.profiles.active=my-profile -jar my-proj.jar --spring.config.location=file:///opt/ms/configrepo/MyProj.yml >> logs/MyProj.out 2>&1 &
```

Comment: Linux killing the process for inactivity or too much memory being used.

Comment: I agree with @M.Deinum. Make sure you have enough ram on your multi node setup. Linux might be killing it due to lack of resources in the machine. Check the memory usage.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks!! Will check and update.

Comment: Adding the logs might help find root cause.

Comment: I concur with the above conclusion about the memory.